# Small mercury spill

Tags: mercury

few weeks ago a thermometer for home use (temperature measuring) broke under our bed on our wood floor 11/18. We cleaned the spill using paper and safely removed it from the house. We ventilated properly for 24 hours.
On 11/21 when I was cleaning I noticed something silver under the bed. Did not come to mind it could be mercury left over. I cleaned properly, vacuumed, and steam mopped.

Today 11/29 on the same place I saw silver beds and line, and like a fool I cleaned with wet wipes and threw it out.

I am almost 9 months pregnant and super worried. How can I clean up properly, is it dangerous and why is it showing up. It looks like a large quantity, from such a small thermometer.

Comment: I encourage you to seek information from reputable, real-life sources. What you are describing is potentially quite dangerous but the internet is not the proper resource for you here.